# Graph fine-tuning: Learning how to condense the x-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am new to R and have been trying to create a graph using ggplot. I have been able to make a lot of progress and have created the image below:

[image: Graph image]

My question is more about the fine-tuning of the graph itself. Currently, I have one value in the x-axis and would like to "trim" the sides of the graph so it can be smaller. I have been reading online and trying to figure out a way to use scale_x_continuous() to define X, but it does not seem to work. Is there a way to edit the dimensions of the graph in this way?

```
<ggplot(positivevalues, aes(x=Valence, y=Value, shape=Categories, color=Categories)) + geom_point(aes(size=5), stat="identity", position
= position_jitter(w = 0.02, h = 0.1)) + labs(title="X", x="EHR", y="Number of Times Codes Applied", subtitle="X") + theme_bw() +
ylim(min=0,max=50) + scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0,0)) +
scale_y_continuous(limits =c(0, 50)) + guides(colour =
guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=4))) + scale_shape_manual(values
= c(17, 18, 16, 8, 15, 9)) + scale_color_manual(values = c("darkgreen", "darkorange", "blue", "black", "darkred",
"blueviolet")) + scale_color_manual(values = c("darkgreen",
"darkorange", "blue", "black", "darkred", "blueviolet")) +labs(x= "   
Positive     \n X") + theme(axis.text=element_text(size=9))>
```

Comment: Could you make a reproducible example?

Comment: Sure! Below is the edited code: Is this helpful? Sorry, still on a steep learning curve.  <<ggplot(dataframe, aes(x=group, y=value, shape=Categories, color=Categories)) + stat="identity", position = position_jitter(w = 0.02, h = 0.1)) + 
ylim(min=0,max=50) + scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0,0)) +
scale_y_continuous(limits =c(0, 50)) + scale_shape_manual(values= c(17, 18, 16, 8, 15, 9)) + scale_color_manual(values = c("darkgreen", "darkorange", "blue", "black", "darkred",
"blueviolet")) + scale_color_manual(values = c("darkgreen",
"darkorange", "blue", "black", "darkred", "blueviolet"))>>

Answer (score 0):

```
library(ggplot2)
positivevalues <- data.frame(Valence=rep("n=p",6), Value=c(0.1,0.5,2,2,18,35), 
                             Categories=LETTERS[1:6])

set.seed(123)
ggplot(positivevalues, aes(x=as.numeric(Valence), y=Value, 
                           shape=Categories, color=Categories)) + 
geom_point(aes(size=5), stat="identity", position=position_jitter(w = 0.02, h = 0.1)) + 
labs(title="X", x="EHR", y="Number of Times Codes Applied", subtitle="X") + theme_bw() +
scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0.95,1.05), breaks=1, labels="n=p") +
scale_y_continuous(limits =c(0, 50)) + 
guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=4))) + 
scale_shape_manual(values= c(17, 18, 16, 8, 15, 9)) + 
scale_color_manual(values = c("darkgreen", "darkorange", "blue", 
                              "black", "darkred", "blueviolet")) + 
labs(x= "Positive     \n X") + theme(axis.text=element_text(size=9)) +
theme(legend.position="none")
```

[image]